# Google Spreadsheet - Data validation with variable date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a data validation drop down menu in a cell with a few set terms like: **N/A**, **Booked**, **Waiting**, and a **variable date value** which can be any date.

I have tried creating a data validation with those items and then show warning on incorrect data, but I don't want the warning to show up and also want to make sure it is a correct date entered and with the right format.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) - everything you described can be achieved with a `DataValidation` class

Comment: Thank you Oleg, that's helpfull. However, with the builder how can you define a data validation to allow both items selection and date selection? From what I understand I can choose one or the other, not both simultaneously in the same cell.

Comment: Since you are using apps script, I can think of a better way - drop the data validation and use `onEdit()` trigger instead with `regexp` (or plain conditionals) to check if the data entered into the cell is either a date or one of the three set dates, then use dialog or `msgbox` ui to display warnings. Btw, since you are dealing with this level of complexity (multi-validation) I think you will be better off with an add-on, moving validation to sidebar (but that's subjective)